useState is reverting back to its former value after updating
I'm writing a nextjs ecommerce website, in the product grid section I added a filter option that allows a user to chose a specific category except that the products variables doesn't update whenever I set a new array of products, I have tried every possible solution in my head for now but still the product state doesn't update, pls I'm stranded and need help with a solution.
Here's a snippet of the code for choosing a specific category
///This function chooses the products category
    const chooseCategory = async (e: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, globalThis.MouseEvent>, _id: number): Promise<void> => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setCategory(() => false)
        setCategoryId(() => _id)
        const category: string = categoryOptions[_id]

        const newProduct = sortByCategory(productList, category)
        console.log('Product: ', category, newProduct)
        setProducts(() => [...newProduct])
        console.log('Products: ', products)
    }

and here's the full code
"use client"
///Product Grid component

///Libraries -->
import { useRouter, usePathname } from 'next/navigation';
import { useState, useEffect, MouseEvent } from 'react';
import styles from "./productGrid.module.scss"
import { IProduct, IClientInfo } from '@/config/interfaces';
import { groupList, sortOptions as sortOption, sortProductByOrder, sortProductByLatest, sortProductByPrice, categories, sortByCategory, routeStyle } from '@/config/utils'
import TuneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Tune';
import KeyboardArrowLeftIcon from '@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowLeft';
import KeyboardArrowRightIcon from '@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowRight';
import Image from 'next/image';
import { useClientInfoStore } from "@/config/store";
import ProductCard from '@/components/cards/product/ProductCard';
import CategoryIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Category';
import { notify } from '@/config/clientUtils';

///Commencing the code 
/**
 * @title Product Component
 * @returns The Product component
 */
const ProductGrid = ({ product_, view_ }: { product_: Array<IProduct>, view_: string | undefined }) => {
    const routerPath = usePathname();
    const [productList, setProductList] = useState(product_)
    const [products, setProducts] = useState<Array<IProduct>>([])
    const [pcCurrentIndex, setPcCurrentIndex] = useState(0)
    const [mobileCurrentIndex, setMobileCurrentIndex] = useState(0)
    const [sort, setSort] = useState(false)
    const [sortId, setSortId] = useState(0)
    const [sortOptions, setSortOptions] = useState(sortOption)
    const [category, setCategory] = useState<boolean>(false)
    const [categoryId, setCategoryId] = useState<number>(0)
    const [categoryOptions, setCategoryOptions] = useState<Array<string>>(["All", ...categories.map((category) => category.name)]) 
    const [pcTotalPage, setPcTotalPage] = useState<Array<any>>([])
    const [mobileTotalPage, setMobileTotalPage] = useState<Array<any>>([])
    const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState<number>(54400);
    const [width, setWidth] = useState<number>(typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.screen ? window.screen.width : 0)
    const [view, setView] = useState<string | undefined>(view_)

    // const res_ = await fetch(`${domainName}/api/product`)
    // console.log("Res: ", res_.json())

    useEffect(() => {
        setProducts(() => productList)
    }, [products, productList])

    ///
    useEffect(() => {
        const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            //console.log("Effect: ", products)
            setTimeLeft((prevTimeLeft) => prevTimeLeft - 1);
        }, 1000);

        return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    }, [products, productList, product_]);

    ///

    // useEffect(() => {
        
    //     const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    //         //console.log("checking screen width")
    //         if (width <= 550) {
    //             const totalPage = groupList(productList, 6) //This gets the total products in groups of 6
    //             setMobileTotalPage(totalPage)
    //             setProducts(totalPage[mobileCurrentIndex])
    //             //console.log("check: ", mobileCurrentIndex)
    //         } else {
    //             const totalPage = groupList(productList, 12) //This gets the total products in groups of 12
    //             setPcTotalPage(totalPage)
    //             setProducts(totalPage[pcCurrentIndex])
    //         };
    //         //console.log('Products: ', products)
    //     }, 500);

    //     return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    // }, [mobileCurrentIndex, pcCurrentIndex, products, sort, sortId, productList, width]);

    ///
    useEffect(() => {
        if (timeLeft === 0) {
        setTimeLeft(86400);
        }
    }, [timeLeft]);

    ///This function filters the products
    const filterProduct = async (e: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, globalThis.MouseEvent>, sort: number): Promise<void> => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setSort(false)
        setSortId(sort)

        if (sort === 0) {
            product_ = sortProductByOrder(productList)
            //setProductList(() => [...product_])
            setProducts(() => [...product_])
        } else if (sort === 1) {
            product_ = sortProductByLatest(productList)
            //product_ = sortByCategory(productList, "Health & Personal Care")
            //setProductList(() => [...product_])
            setProducts(() => [...product_])
        } else if (sort === 2) {
            product_ = sortProductByPrice(productList, "descend")
            //setProductList(() => [...product_])
            setProducts(() => [...product_])
        } else if (sort === 3) {
            product_ = sortProductByPrice(productList, "ascend")
            //setProductList(() => [...product_])
            setProducts(() => [...product_])
        }
    }

    ///This function chooses the products category
    const chooseCategory = async (e: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, globalThis.MouseEvent>, _id: number): Promise<void> => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setCategory(() => false)
        setCategoryId(() => _id)
        const category: string = categoryOptions[_id]

        const newProduct = sortByCategory(productList, category)
        console.log('New Product: ', category, newProduct)
        setProducts(() => [...newProduct])
        console.log('Products: ', products)
    }

    return (
        <main className={`${styles.main} ${routeStyle(routerPath, styles)}`} id="products">
            <div className={styles.product_list}>
                <div className={styles.filters}>
                    <div className={`${styles.sort_section}`}>
                        <button className={styles.sort_button} onClick={() => setSort(!sort)}>
                            <TuneIcon />
                        </button> 
                        <span>Sort</span>
                        <div className={`${styles.sort_option} ${!sort ? styles.inactiveSort : ""}`}>
                            {sortOptions.map((option, _id) => (
                                <button key={_id} className={sortId === _id ? styles.activeSortButton : styles.inActiveSortButton} onClick={(e) => filterProduct(e, option.id)}>
                                    {option.name}
                                </button>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles.category}>
                        <span>Category</span>
                        <button className={styles.category_button} onClick={() => setCategory(() => !category)}>
                            <CategoryIcon />
                        </button> 
                        <div className={`${styles.category_option} ${!category ? styles.inactiveSort : ""}`}>
                            {categoryOptions.map((category, _id) => (
                                <button key={_id} className={categoryId === _id ? styles.activeSortButton : styles.inActiveSortButton} onClick={(e) => chooseCategory(e, _id)}>{category}</button>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.product_carousel}>
                    {products ? products.map((product, _id) => (
                        <ProductCard key={_id} product_={product} view={view} />
                    )) : (<></>)}
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </main>
    );
};
  
export default ProductGrid;

From the above code snippet, the filterProduct function works and updates perfectly fine but not the chooseCategory function. What might be the issue?

nope, Mine isn't updating at all, its almost like I never wrote the setState logic

In that case you'll want to get rid of that last console.log statement which makes it appear to be a duplicate, and update the question to clarify how specifically you're observing the problem.  Perhaps you could provide a [mcve] as a React code snippet?

I already solved the issue, I did get rid of the last console.log and inserted it in an useEffect hook which actually showed that the state was actually updating but then I had another useEffect hook that was updating the state back to its former value so it looked like it was never updating

It looks fine to me. Why you're setting states in a callback function?
And one more thing, when you console.log('Products: ', products) right after setting state, It will not show you the updated state. Update your code as below 
const chooseCategory = async (e: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, globalThis.MouseEvent>, _id: number): Promise<void> => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setCategory(false)
    setCategoryId(_id)
    const category: string = categoryOptions[_id]

    const newProduct = sortByCategory(productList, category)
    console.log('New Product: ', category, newProduct)
    setProducts([...newProduct])
}

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Products: ', products)
}, [products]);


Thanks, already solved the issue
the useEffect hook showed that the state was actually updating but then I had another useEffect hook that was updating the state back to its former value so it looked like it was never updating
